# When executing hex string, first instruction skipped

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, linux-mint, gnu-assembler

I'm writing a program which spawns a shell from a pure hex string in a c aplication. If I run the shell executable that generated the hex string, the program runs normally and start the session. But when I run it in this c code (which by the way I got from another post in stackoverflow) in gdb and break right before the start of the shell execution, I noticed that the pointer to the first instruction is poiting to the second instruction of the assembly code, not the first. The c code is

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{

  char code[] = {
    0xe8, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x62, 
    0x69, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x62, 0x61, 0x73, 0x68, 
    0x5f, 0xb0, 0x3b, 0x48, 0x31, 0xf6, 0x48, 
    0x31, 0xd2, 0x0f, 0x05
};

  void *buf;

  /* copy code to executable buffer */    
  buf = mmap (0,sizeof(code),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
          MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0);
  memcpy (buf, code, sizeof(code));

  /* run code */
  ((void (*) (void))buf)();

  return 0;
}
```

the shell:

```
.globl _start
.text

_start:
        call chamaexecve
        variaveis:
            .asciz "/bin/bash"


    chamaexecve:
        pop %rdi # first instruction of the call
        mov $59, %al # second instruction of the call
        xor %rsi, %rsi
        xor %rdx, %rdx

        syscall
```

In gdb, disasembling main, the `callq` where the shellcode is started is pointed

```
0x0000000000400596 <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400597 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040059a <+4>:    sub    $0x40,%rsp
0x000000000040059e <+8>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
0x00000000004005a7 <+17>:   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x00000000004005ab <+21>:   xor    %eax,%eax
0x00000000004005ad <+23>:   movb   $0xe8,-0x30(%rbp)
0x00000000004005b1 <+27>:   movb   $0xa,-0x2f(%rbp)
0x00000000004005b5 <+31>:   movb   $0x0,-0x2e(%rbp)
0x00000000004005b9 <+35>:   movb   $0x0,-0x2d(%rbp)
0x00000000004005bd <+39>:   movb   $0x0,-0x2c(%rbp)
0x00000000004005c1 <+43>:   movb   $0x2f,-0x2b(%rbp)
0x00000000004005c5 <+47>:   movb   $0x62,-0x2a(%rbp)
0x00000000004005c9 <+51>:   movb   $0x69,-0x29(%rbp)
0x00000000004005cd <+55>:   movb   $0x6e,-0x28(%rbp)
0x00000000004005d1 <+59>:   movb   $0x2f,-0x27(%rbp)
0x00000000004005d5 <+63>:   movb   $0x62,-0x26(%rbp)
0x00000000004005d9 <+67>:   movb   $0x61,-0x25(%rbp)
0x00000000004005dd <+71>:   movb   $0x73,-0x24(%rbp)
0x00000000004005e1 <+75>:   movb   $0x68,-0x23(%rbp)
0x00000000004005e5 <+79>:   movb   $0x5f,-0x22(%rbp)
0x00000000004005e9 <+83>:   movb   $0xb0,-0x21(%rbp)
0x00000000004005ed <+87>:   movb   $0x3b,-0x20(%rbp)
0x00000000004005f1 <+91>:   movb   $0x48,-0x1f(%rbp)
0x00000000004005f5 <+95>:   movb   $0x31,-0x1e(%rbp)
0x00000000004005f9 <+99>:   movb   $0xf6,-0x1d(%rbp)
0x00000000004005fd <+103>:  movb   $0x48,-0x1c(%rbp)
0x0000000000400601 <+107>:  movb   $0x31,-0x1b(%rbp)
0x0000000000400605 <+111>:  movb   $0xd2,-0x1a(%rbp)
0x0000000000400609 <+115>:  movb   $0xf,-0x19(%rbp)
0x000000000040060d <+119>:  movb   $0x5,-0x18(%rbp)
0x0000000000400611 <+123>:  mov    $0x0,%r9d
0x0000000000400617 <+129>:  mov    $0xffffffff,%r8d
0x000000000040061d <+135>:  mov    $0x22,%ecx
0x0000000000400622 <+140>:  mov    $0x7,%edx
0x0000000000400627 <+145>:  mov    $0x19,%esi
0x000000000040062c <+150>:  mov    $0x0,%edi
0x0000000000400631 <+155>:  callq  0x400470 <mmap@plt>
0x0000000000400636 <+160>:  mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
0x000000000040063a <+164>:  mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
0x000000000040063e <+168>:  mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rdx
0x0000000000400642 <+172>:  mov    %rdx,(%rax)
0x0000000000400645 <+175>:  mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdx
0x0000000000400649 <+179>:  mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
0x000000000040064d <+183>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
0x0000000000400651 <+187>:  mov    %rdx,0x10(%rax)
0x0000000000400655 <+191>:  movzbl -0x18(%rbp),%edx
0x0000000000400659 <+195>:  mov    %dl,0x18(%rax)
0x000000000040065c <+198>:  mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
**0x0000000000400660 <+202>:    callq  *%rax**
0x0000000000400662 <+204>:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400667 <+209>:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
0x000000000040066b <+213>:  xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
0x0000000000400674 <+222>:  je     0x40067b <main+229>
0x0000000000400676 <+224>:  callq  0x400460 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
0x000000000040067b <+229>:  leaveq 
0x000000000040067c <+230>:  retq
```

I set the breakpoint to this call running `tb * 0x0000000000400660`
printing rax at this breakpoint gives:

> (gdb) print /x $rax
>
> $2 = 0x7ffff7ff5000

and `x/8i 0x7ffff7ff5000`:

```
0x7ffff7ff5000: callq  0x7ffff7ff500f
0x7ffff7ff5005: (bad)  
0x7ffff7ff5006: (bad)  
0x7ffff7ff5007: imul   $0x68736162,0x2f(%rsi),%ebp
0x7ffff7ff500e: pop    %rdi # first instruction of the call
0x7ffff7ff500f:  mov    $0x3b,%al # second instruction of the call
0x7ffff7ff5011: xor    %rsi,%rsi
0x7ffff7ff5014: xor    %rdx,%rdx
```

Also, if I print the hexs from this point, it shows me the shellcode aligned:

> x/25xb 0x7ffff7ff5000
> 0x7ffff7ff5000: 0xe8    0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x2f    0x62    0x69
> 0x7ffff7ff5008: 0x6e    0x2f    0x62    0x61    0x73    0x68    0x5f    0xb0
> 0x7ffff7ff5010: 0x3b    0x48    0x31    0xf6    0x48    0x31    0xd2    0x0f
> 0x7ffff7ff5018: 0x05

The c code was compiled with `$ gcc -ggdb -o executahex executahex.c` and the shell with `$ as -gstabs -o shellf-test.o shellf-test.s` `$ ld -o shellf-test shellf-test.o`

Comment: You said _in gdb and break right before the start of the shell execution,_ but you don't show how you set that breakpoint. One possibility is that you did something like `break somelabel` or `break 0xsomeaddress`. What you might try doing is `break *somelabel` or `break *0xsomeaddress` . Notice the addition of the *. By default setting breaks will cause GDB to find the first instruction that it doesn't believe is part of function prologue.

Comment: ok, edited in the question, both using break or tbreak gives the same result for rax in this point

Comment: The only problem is your code is wrong. `0xe8, 0x0a,` should be `0xe8, 0x09,` and that is because your hex doesn't match the asm code, where you used `.asciz` which puts a zero at the end. Your hex does not have that zero which shifts everything by one byte.

Comment: That is strange, I generated this hex using `objdump -d shellf-test`. Here is the dump: http://pastebin.com/EFteaTxZ

Comment: `objdump` doesn't like disassembling data (the `...` is where your zero byte is hidden). It also doesn't make much sense to disassemble if you only need the hex. A listing file (e.g. `as -al`) works better ;) `objdump -d --disassemble-zeroes` also works (`-dz` for short).

Comment: If using objdump you want to disassemble the zeroes. You can pass `-z` to display the zeroes. By default they were suppressed and displayed as `...`  after `40007f:   69 6e 2f 62 61 73 68    imul   $0x68736162,0x2f(%rsi),%ebp`

Comment: I reassembled using `as -al` and called objdump with `-dz` and got the zeros. However, the output in the opcode still 0x0a not 0x09

Comment: `0x0a` is okay if you have the zero. It's the length of your string. No zero, 9, with zero 10. PS: after `as -al` no need for `objdump`, you get the hex directly printed.